# Ruby on Rails - Validations and updating/creating multiple objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

First, what I'd like to do - I have some incoming parameters that can be fairly large for updating objects on the server (~500 objects worth of attributes could be normal at times).

My logic goes something like this:

```
def create_objects(object_attribute_array)
    errors = []
    return if object_attribute_array.blank?

    # Client ids are generated on clients to help with objects that were actually already created on the server but not returned due to faulty network connections
    incoming_client_ids = object_attribute_array.pluck(:client_id)
    existing_objects = current_user.objects.where(client_id: incoming_client_ids)

    # commit array in transaction - if after_rollback, error panic mode
    object_attribute_array.each do |obj|
      if existing_objects.pluck(:client_id).include?(obj[:client_id])
        # update it conditionally based on update time by changing the incoming object parameters but do not save
      else
        # create, validate, add to transaction
      end
    end
  end
```

So, what I would like to do (I think?):

It seems that logically I would get the existing objects first, overwrite any existing object info using incoming parameters, but don't save the object to the database yet. Just validate it and then hold it in an array of validated objects.
Then, new up and validate objects that weren't found to be existing and add those to the array as well. Since theoretically saving all objects in the array would work smoothly, I should then wrap it in a transaction for a single database call?

Or should I actually try to simply save the array objects one-by-one so that individual object errors will be returned but the database transaction won't rollback on me?

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've read a bunch on transactions and are familiar with how they work, but I'm not seeing a lot on validate -> add to array in memory -> best practice for persisting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `activerecord-import` library for bulk inserting data. It also supports validation (`:validate` option) and updating existing records (`on_duplicate_key_update` option).

https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki

https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/On-Duplicate-Key-Update

The principle is the same: you form an array of `ActiveRecord` objects, then persist them in one or a few queries depending on associated records.